# How To Scale Azure Service Fabric Actors Of The Same Service Type?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm new to Azure Service Fabric and the one part I'm trying to fully understand is how the scaling works. I currently have a Azure Service Fabric Application which consists of a stateless Reliable service web api and a stateful Actor Service.

While debugging this locally, I see that a single application is created with 5 nodes. The api is created on all 5 nodes as it had an instance count of -1 and the actor service is create with a primary on one node and 2 replicas on 2 other nodes.

The web api will create many actor instances (but its not really known how many in total there will be). Each one has its own unique state data and all these actors get created on the primary node the service was created on.

But how does this scale? Eventually, it would be possible for too many actor instances to be on that primary node so how can we scale this out? Will Azure do this for us? Do we need some sort of manager service? What would that manager service do - create a new actor service instance on a different node? create a new application instance? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

To provide scalability and reliability, Service Fabric distributes actors throughout the cluster and automatically migrates them from failed nodes to healthy ones as required. Distribution, scalability, reliability, and automatic failover are all provided by virtue of the fact that actors are running inside a stateful Reliable Service called the Actor Service.

Actors are distributed across the partitions of the Actor Service, and those partitions are distributed across the nodes in a Service Fabric cluster. Each service partition contains a set of actors. Service Fabric manages distribution and failover of the service partitions.

For example, an actor service with nine partitions deployed to three nodes using the default actor partition placement would be distributed thusly: 
[image]

Reference - [Introduction to Service Fabric Reliable Actors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction)

Comment: Yes I know about partitions. The point was, partitioning assumes you know how many partitions you will need at time of deployment. My situation is I don't know how many actors will be active so cannot accurately calculate the necessary partition schema at time of deployment. I need something more dynamic.

Comment: The number of partitions is not dynamic, changing it requires redeployment of your actor service and dealing with the impact on existing state.

Partition planning is to choose the correct number of partitions to begin with. From a Service Fabric perspective, there is nothing that prevents you from starting out with a higher number of partitions than anticipated for your scenario. In fact, assuming the maximum number of partitions is a valid approach.

Comment: You are not listening to what I am saying.

Comment: Seemingly he answered your question implicitly describing fixed number of partitions to begin with and that defines maximum capacity. I don't think Service Fabric can dynamically increase nodes, meaning partitions as well based on discussion in this thread. Please someone corrects me if that is the case.

Comment: @JP_medevice In case of actors (`ActorService` use the Int64 partition) the number of partitions cannot be changed after deployment. However you can add more nodes to the cluster itself in both [hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-scale-up-down) and onpremise(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-windows-server-add-remove-nodes) scenarios.